# how to display this notification in Android?

Tags: java, android, ios

Im looking for this library to display this kind of notification that i could display when there is a new update on my list.

Here is the sample like in Facebook or LinkedIn.

[image]

Comment: I don't have code though but you can try it like this in Framelayout keep a  textview and do toggle of visible/gone with that textview. onClick of that textview hide that texview and go to the bottom/top as u r impl. to show latest posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library [popup bubble](https://github.com/webianks/PopupBubble) for the above requirement

In your xml

```
<com.webianks.library.PopupBubble
  android:layout_margin="16dp"
  android:id="@+id/popup_bubble"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
/>
```

In your activity

```
PopupBubble popupBubble = (PopupBubble) findViewById(R.id.popup_bubble);

popupBubble.setPopupBubbleListener(new PopupBubble.PopupBubbleClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void bubbleClicked(Context context) {

                //popup_bubble is clicked  
            }
        });
```

you can also attach this to your recycler view

```
popupBubble.setRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Answer (score 0):

set an onScrollListener to your RecyclerView. On every scroll call your API which fetches the data.

Use a TextView with Gone/Visible fadein/fadeout animation if new data is added. This can be simply done from the adapter.